# Find a quadratic polynomial which when divided by (x-1), (x-2), (x-3) leaves remainders 11, 22, 37 respectively.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, recreational-mathematics

Find a quadratic polynomial which when divided by $(x-1)$, $(x-2)$, $(x-3)$ leaves remainders $11, 22, 37$ respectively.

Comment: Show your efforts atleast.

Comment: Let $f(x)$

$=(x-a)(x-b)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$
$\left(\dfrac p{x-a}+\dfrac q{x-b}+\dfrac r{x-1}+\dfrac s{x-2}+\dfrac t{x-3}\right)$

Comment: FOUND! It's $P(x)=2 x^2+5 x+4$

Comment: We know that the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x-\alpha$ is $f(\alpha)$.

If we say that $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ then we have \begin{align}a\times 1^2+b\times 1+c&=11\\a+b+c&=11\tag{1}\\\\a\times 2^2+b\times 2+c&=22\\4a+2b+c&=22\tag{2}\\\\a\times 3^2+b\times 3+c&=37\\9a+3b+c&=37\tag{3}\end{align}
We then have $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns so we can solve these for $a,b,c$:
$(2)-(1)$: $$3a+b=11\tag{4}$$
$(3)-(2)$: $$5a+b=15\tag{5}$$
$(5)-(4)$: $$2a=4\\a=2$$
From $(4)$: $$3\times 2+b=11\\b=5$$
From $(1)$: $$2+5+c=11\\c=4$$
And therefore, our quadratic is: $$f(x)=2x^2+5x+4$$

Comment: I was too slow to post this as an answer. If it gets reopened, I will convert this to an answer, not a comment

Comment: Thankyou very much sir. You just saved my day. Tomorrow are my exams and I didn't know how to solve this and my teachers don't care about me.

Comment: @proneon You're welcome, although I prefer the term 'miss' (as my username may suggest, I am female!) :D

Comment: Sorry about that miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c.$ Then by the given conditions, $$f(x)=(x-1)\phi_1(x)+11$$ $$f(x)=(x-2)\phi_2(x)+22$$ $$f(x)=(x-3)\phi_3(x)+37,$$ for some polynomials $\phi_1(x),\phi_2(x),\phi_3(x)$ of degree $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting point: write down what it means for a quadratic polynomial $P$ to leave remainder $11$ when divided by $x-1$...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem